# height of dropdown in BasicComboPopup

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

As mentioned, I am now providing workable code for my problem.

```
**HTML to Run Applet**
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div >
<APPLET CODE="Main.class" WIDTH="800" HEIGHT="500">
</APPLET>
</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

**Applet Class**

```
public class Main extends Applet{
   public void init(){
       JComboBoxUI c = new JComboBoxUI();
       c.addItem("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
       c.addItem("B");
c.addItem("C");
c.addItem("D");
c.addItem("E");
c.addItem("F");
c.addItem("G");
c.addItem("H");    
c.addItem("I");
c.addItem("J");
c.addItem("K");
c.addItem("L");
c.setName("Combo Box");
c.setSelectedItem("D");
       c.setMaximumRowCount(20);
       c.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,20));
     add(c);
   }
}
```

**MetalComboBox - override BasicComboPopUp**

```
public class JComboBoxUI extends JComboBox{

     public void updateUI() {
          setUI(new CustomComboBoxUI());
       }

       public void addPopupMenuListener(PopupMenuListener l) {
           CustomComboBoxUI ui = (CustomComboBoxUI)getUI();
          ui.addPopupMenuListener(l);
       }


    public class CustomComboBoxUI extends MetalComboBoxUI {
           protected JPopupMenu _popup;
            protected ComboPopup createPopup() {
                 BasicComboPopup popup = new BasicComboPopup(comboBox) {
                    public JScrollPane createScroller() {
                        JScrollPane j = new JScrollPane( list, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER,
                              ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
                        return j;
                     }
                 };         
                 _popup = (JPopupMenu)popup;
                 return popup;
              }
           @Override 
           protected void installListeners() {
               super.installListeners();
           }

           public void addPopupMenuListener(PopupMenuListener l) {
              if (_popup != null)
                 _popup.addPopupMenuListener(l);
           }
        }
}
```

**Problem**

If you will run this, you will see that vertical scrollbar is not coming(as set in JScrollPane) and some elements are not showing up. I want to increase height of Popup so I can see all elements. Any Help

Comment: Take a look at my solution. Let me know whether that is what you are asking.

Comment: Somewhere in your BasicComboPopup class, implement user3437460's solution.  In the code you're showing, remove the setPreferredSize and setMaximumSize statements.  Since you provided a code snippet, I'm providing a solution snippet.  If you want actual help, paste a **runnable** example of your problem in your question.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have overridden BasicComboPopup class and overridden getPopupHeightForRowCount(int maxRowCount) method to include height of horizontal scroll bar.

```
 public class OverrideComboPopup extends BasicComboPopup {

    private JScrollPane sPane;
    public KronosComboPopup(KronosComboBox combo) {
        super(combo);
        setBackground(GUIResources.POPUP_MENU_BACKGROUND);
    }

 public JScrollPane createScroller() {
        sPane = new JScrollPane( list, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                      ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        return sPane;
     }

     //Overrides the getPopupHeightForRowCount to include the height of horizontal bar.
     protected int getPopupHeightForRowCount(int maxRowCount) {
        int currentElementCount = comboBox.getModel().getSize();
        int rowCount = Math.min( maxRowCount, currentElementCount );
        if (rowCount==0) return rowCount;
        int ht = super.getPopupHeightForRowCount(maxRowCount);
        double cWidth = comboBox.getSize().getWidth();
        double vWidth = list.getPreferredScrollableViewportSize().getWidth();
        if (vWidth>cWidth) {
           int barHt = sPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().getHeight();
           //Sets the default height of scroll bar
           if (barHt==0) barHt = 16;
           ht = ht + barHt;
        }
        return ht;
     }


    }
```

Let me know if you stuck anytime with this, contact me on chauhanvineesh@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

> height of dropdown in JComboBox in swings

If you want to set the number of rows of items to be shown in the JCombobox when user click on the list, you can use this method from the JComboBox itself.

```
setMaximumRowCount(int count)
```

Comment: I know it and I set it to 20. but it property is overridden once we use custom popup.

Comment: @vineeshchauhan Overridden? Are you asking about BasicComboPopup or JComboBox?

Comment: Yes. In my code, BasicComboPopup is used to provide custom feature to dropdown. please see code snippet.